# Overriding enumerate for custom class

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerate

I have a [custom class](https://replit.com/@matedevita/CustomEnumerate#main.py) that's essentially a list, but with negative indices being valid indices, rather than referring to elements from the rear of the list.

```
from collections.abc import Sequence


class MultiFloorPlan(Sequence):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._floors = []
        self._subfloors = []

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, MultiFloorPlan):
            return NotImplemented
        return self._subfloors == other._subfloors and self._floors == other._floors

    def _reindex(self, floor):
        if floor >= 0:
            return self._floors, floor
        return self._subfloors, -floor - 1

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._subfloors) + len(self._floors)

    def __getitem__(self, floor):
        floor_list, floor = self._reindex(floor)
        return floor_list[floor]

    def __delitem__(self, floor):
        floor_list, floor = self._reindex(floor)
        del floor_list[floor]

    def __iter__(self):
        for plan in self._subfloors:
            yield plan
        for plan in self._floors:
            yield plan

    def __reversed__(self):
        for plan in reversed(self._floors):
            yield plan
        for plan in reversed(self._subfloors):
            yield plan

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return value in self._subfloors or value in self._floors

    def append(self, subfloor=False):
        if subfloor:
            return self._subfloors.append(None)  # For this example we append a dummy None
        return self._floors.append(None)         # value instead of an actual Plan instance
```

Is it possible to get the built-in `enumerate` to return the floor indices, rather than the values shifted to the non-negative integers? Example:

```
mfp = MultiFloorPlan()
for _ in range(5):
    mfp.append(subfloor=False)
    mfp.append(subfloor=True)

for floor, _ in enumerate(mfp):
    print(floor)
# This prints 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, but I'd like it to print -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: You cannot change what `enumerate` does, but you can change how your class behaves in a `for` loop. Are you sure that you don't simply want `for floor in mfp: print(floor)`?

Comment: Why not just have a custom generator method? Compare dictionaries, which have an `.items()` method instead of overloading `enumerate`.

Comment: @user3840170 That's probably what I'm going to do, `numpy` also defines its own enumerate methods on arrays. I was just wondering if there is a way to override the built-in `enumerate` like there is for other built-in functions and operators (`in`, `[]`, `getattr`, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `enumerate` builtin function operates on arbitrary iterators, so it cannot behave in a special way for your class. However, a clever *user* of `enumerate` can produce the results you want, they just need to set it up properly by passing in an appropriate starting index. You might provide that setup in the class, with a method:

```
def enumerate(self):
    return enumerate(self, -len(self._subfloors))
```